# Render Symfony 5 service as twig global

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering

I'm using a service as twig global variable. In the service constructor I set a default value of the property `$title`. It works initially.... Twig render the property value using the command `{{ service.getTitle() }}` in a template file. But after update the service property by the controllers constructor and rendering the view, the value is not updated at screen. The goal is set a twig global variable by the controllers to render in all views. How to do it?

- twig.yaml

  ```yaml
  twig:
      globals:
          pageMap: "@Base.PageMap"
  ```
- services.yaml

  ```yaml
  services:
      Base.PageMap:
          class : App\Bundle\Base\Services\PageMap
          public: true
  ```
- controller

  ```php
  public function __construct(PageMap $pageMap)
  {
     $pageMap->setTitle('Registration listing');
  }
  ```
- twig template:

  ```html
  <div class="title">{{ pageMap.getTitle() }}</div>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Twig globals are setup at init time and compiled/cached for the duration of an execution.

If you want to update and be able to call things dynamically, you should create a RuntimeExtension (see documentation here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#creating-lazy-loaded-twig-extensions)

Calling it from your template will be a little more expensive (but more correct !)